# How to get autosaclinggroup name with aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-eks

hi guys i need help to solve my problem to get name of autoscalinggroups by using AWS cli with query i try to use this `aws eks describe-nodegroup --cluster-name test-server --nodegroup-name default` but i just wana get output only autoScalingGroups name . i need help please

example output :

```
eks-default-20bfe7fd-620b-c44b-c7e3-33f44221240c5
```

Comment: You will need to query the autoscaling endpoint and look for the tags `eks:cluster-name` and `eks:nodegroup-name`.

Comment: You can try with ```aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups``` and filter with tag option https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html#options and this can help: https://serverfault.com/questions/654791/fetch-autoscaling-group-name-in-aws

Comment: but i need to useing command aws eks for work not from aws autoscaling command

Comment: if using command aws autoscaling you need to know the name of --auto-scaling-group-names thats why i need to query the output only get  to get a name of autoscalinggroups

Answer (score 0):

Auto Scaling Group names can be retrieved using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
aws eks describe-nodegroup --cluster-name test-server --nodegroup-name default \
| jq -r '.nodegroup.resources.autoScalingGroups[].name'
```

The [EKS API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeNodegroup.html#API_DescribeNodegroup_ResponseSyntax) give a clearer picture of the JSON response.